# How do I ignore numeric logs in git?

Tags: git, gitignore

Python [`RotatingFileHandler`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/logging.handlers.html#logging.handlers.RotatingFileHandler) creates logs like `foo.log`, `foo.log.1`, ..., `foo.log.213`....

How do I ignore all these in `git`? (I know that `*.log` are ignored automatically).

E.g., adding

```
*.log.[0-9]
*.log.[0-9][0-9]
*.log.[0-9][0-9][0-9]
```

to [`.gitignore`](https://git-scm.com/docs/gitignore) would probably work for the first 1,000 log files, it looks ugly.

Is there a better way?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you want to be really precise and ignore only files with numeric suffix after `.log.` and excluding things like `x.log.1bar`, then this will do it:

```
*.log.*
!*.log.*[^0-9]*
```

This will match everything containing `.log.`,
excluding patterns where the suffix after `.log.` contains non-digits.
This also excludes `*.log.`.
In effect, it matches only files with numeric suffix after `.log.`.